# Passing numeric variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, numbers, numeric

Why can't I pass the num variable to this function like so:

```
    function getColumnData(num) {
    var colVals = $('#newtable td:nth-child(num)').map(function(){
       return $(this).text();
    }).get();
    alert(colVals);
    }
```

Is there an easy way around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to concatenate the value of `num` with the selector string:

```
var colVals = $('#newtable td:nth-child(' + num + ')').map(function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

Currently you just have a string literal "#newtable td:nth-child(num)", instead of something that makes sense to the selector engine, such as "#newtable td:nth-child(2)".

Answer (score 3):

Because your jQuery selector is a string, you need to 'build' it using concatenation, like so:

```
$('#newtable td:nth-child(' + num + ')')
```

Otherwise `num` is just some characters in the string literal.

Answer (score 1):

try on line 2

```
var colVals = $('#newtable td:nth-child(' + num + ')').map(function(){
```